# How to implement macro nodecallback in C++ vs CPLEX

Tags: c++, cplex

I am trying to implement a macro callback to retrieve objective value at each nodes.
I wrote this code:

```
ILONODECALLBACK0(mycali) {
for (int i = 0; i < getNnodes(); i++) {
cout << "getObjValue"<< getObjValue(i) << endl;
}
}
```

When I run the code it just shows objective value in root node while there is 10 nodes in CPLEX log file. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you please show the full engine log output? At first glance your code looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the code looks correct. Note however that the node callback may not be the right callback to use here. The node callback is invoked when the next node to process is selected. Printing the objective of all open nodes at this point in time may not be what you want.

You can use a solve callback and capture the node's relaxation value from that callback.

In case you want to have more help you will have to update your question with the full log output, including the output from your callback.

Comment: Thank you dear Daniel. I used UserCutCallback for get this information.